# how to update y axis for NVD3's multichart?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization, nvd3.js

There is a stacked area chart built with NVD3's multichart. The values in the chart can change, and I want the y Axis to scale according to the selected values.

How can I update the yAxis for multiChart?

I have used forceY to change the yAxis in other NVD3 charts, but forceY doesn't work with multiChart.

Below are several strategies. The last strategy changes the value of the domain, but the new value is not reflected on the chart.

Thanks for any help offered.

```
        //existing domain values -- to be changed
        chart.stack1.yDomain()
         => [-.1, -1.92]

        //new values that I want the y axis to use
        let [padStart, padEnd] = [.12, 0.27]; 

        //DOESNT WORK - this changes the yDomain of stack1, but does not change yAxis1.domain
        //  chart.stack1.yDomain([padStart, padEnd]);

        //DOESNT WORK - error -chart.forceY is not a function
        //  chart.forceY(padStart, padEnd);

        //DOESNT WORK - error - chart.yAxis1.forceY is not a function
        //  chart.yAxis1.forceY(padStart, padEnd);

        //DOESNT WORK - this does not change domain value
        //  chart.yAxis1.scale().domain([padStart, padEnd]);

        //WORKS -- this changes domain value, but the view doesn't update
        chart.yAxis1.domain([padStart, padEnd]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct approach for multichart is to access the yDomain directly:

`chart.yDomain([padStart, padEnd])`

Comment: is this the only way? I saw a changeset related to setting `forceY` for multichart but didn't understand how to implement it.